# How can I upload a single file using ngx-dropzone in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, frontend, dropzone

I'm using ngx-dropzone in Angular to upload a profile picture with drop zone, but I want the user to upload only one file instead of multiple. Is there a way using ngx-dropzone?

Here you can see the demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just disable multiple files upload. Like code below.

```
<ngx-dropzone [multiple]="false" (change)="onSelect($event)"></ngx-dropzone>
```

Comment: The multiple attribute is for selecting multiple files at once via the dialog, it doesn't stop from actually adding multiple files

Comment: [multiple]="false" is not working. after using this also we can upload multiple files at a time. there are issues raised in git also.  https://github.com/georgipeltekov/ngx-file-drop/issues/179

Comment: You can manipulate the files array in the controller to hold only one file, when a new one is selected.